# Custom handling of invalid character inputs

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Here's the scenario. I have a textbox on the UI which is bound to a double property. If a character, say a '#' is typed in the textbox, the WPF validation is not enough for the application. I need to display a custom message and also disable some controls from the code. (These controls to be disabled are not part of the xaml.) As of now, the only way I could think of to do this is to bind the textbox to a string property and use the TryParse method. However, this will be a huge inconvenience. Is there a way to get the notification that an invalid character has been entered, without having to change the property to the string type?

Answer (score 0):

well i use the "string" solution in my viewmodel. works best with IDataErrorInfo and binding.

but sometimes i also use a InputMaskbehavior for my Textboxe. so the user can just input characters wich is defined for the inputmask.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the MVVM pattern then you probably should have a string property in your ViewModel as this is what is entered on a Textbox. Even when you need the double for your model you have a string on your view. Then you can do whatever validation you need on the string property. Something like:

```
public string TextProperty
{
    get
    {
        return _textProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_textProperty != value)
        {
            _doubleProperty = this.TransformAndValidateString(value);               
             _textProperty = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding disabling controls when an error is present look here:

[IDataErrorInfo](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/06/validate-your-application-using.html)

Comment: Is there no way to find out in the code that a wrong value has been entered? Something like listening to the exception raised by IDataErrorInfo?
P.S. Sorry if the questions are too basic. I am a beginner.

Comment: IDataErrorInfo does not raise exceptions. It provides a method that returns a string with an error message if the validation fails. Why this approach does not work for you? Remember to upvote if the answer helps you.